# Execute airflow tasks in for loop

Tags: python-2.7, workflow, airflow

I am trying to create a dag where I get table names from a table tracker in one task and then I want to run different SQL operations(tasks) on each table
I am able to pass table names from one task to another task using xcom but task in the for loop are not getting executed
I am not even able to see those tasks in web UI

```
from __future__ import print_function 
from airflow import DAG 
from airflow.operators.sensors import SqlSensor 
from airflow import hooks 
from airflow.operators import BashOperator, PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime,date, timedelta 
import logging 
import time
from time import sleep
import psycopg2
from pprint import pprint


default_args = {
    'owner' : 'navjot',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016,12,29,23,0),
    'email': ['navjot@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    #'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}




dag = DAG('sensesql_v5', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval = '@hourly')



""" This function gives all the tables which are ready to be enriched, List of tables names would be generated using taskt2"""
def get_tablename_enrich():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='xxx',user=config['user'],password=config['password'],host=config['host'],port = config['port'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = """Select fore_table_name from results.forecasting_run_tabt where enrich_status = 'pending';"""
    cursor.execute(query)

    row = cursor.fetchall()
    table_name=[]
    for r in row:
        table_name.append(r[0])
    conn.close()
    return table_name

#def testpo():
#    value1 = 4
#    return value1

#value=4
#def push_function(value):
#    return value

""" sensing table tracket in t1"""
t1 = SqlSensor(
    task_id='sqlsensing',
    poke_interval=10,
    timeout = 3200,
    sql = """Select * from results.forecasting_run_tabt where enrich_status = 'pending';""",
    conn_id = 'postgresterra',
    dag=dag
    )


"""getting table names with a condition"""
t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='testpo1',
    python_callable=get_tablename_enrich,
    dag=dag)


"""run enrichment SQL operations on each table which we got from task t2. There is just on task in this function
 we are going to run 11-12 tasks on each table"""
def run_enrich_ontables(*args, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pprint(kwargs)
    tablenames = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='testpo1')
    pprint(tablenames)
    for i in range(len(tablenames)):
        t4 = PostgresOperator(
           task_id='testxcom'+str(i),
           sql = "update results.forecasting_run_tabt set enrich_status = 'running' where fore_table_name = '{}';".format(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='testpo1')[i]),
           postgres_conn_id = 'postgrestest',
               autocommit = True,
           dag=dag)
        t4.set_upstream(t3)

"""This task is calling function which is enriching tables"""
t3 = PythonOperator(
      task_id='run_all_tables',
      provide_context=True,
      python_callable=run_enrich_ontables,
      dag=dag)



t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t2)
```

Comment: Is it possible to move your `run_enrich_ontables` logic out of the function? My suspicion is that you're running into scoping issues where `t3` is not known within the function (and thus it's not being set as upstream from `t4`).

Comment: in that case I cannot use output of task t2 using xcom_pull as it  will only work in a function not outside a function. Xcoms just work between tasks not outside of a task

Comment: As @Greg Mentioned, it looks like some errors in your file that cannot compile, that's probably why you don't see it on UI. I would do `python your_dag_file.py` to first figure out the error from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think `dag` in the execution context of your `run_enrich_ontables` function is `None`. In order to reference macros in the context within a function passed to a `PythonOperator` you should use the `kwargs` dict like you did with `ti`. Either add

```
dag = kwargs['dag']
```

to the top of your function so you can reference `dag` later or change your t4 definition to use kwargs directly

```
    t4 = PostgresOperator(
       task_id='testxcom'+str(i),
       sql = "update results.forecasting_run_tabt set enrich_status = 'running' where fore_table_name = '{}';".format(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='testpo1')[i]),
       postgres_conn_id = 'postgrestest',
           autocommit = True,
       dag=kwargs['dag'])
```